# Aggregate in UPDATE command

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to update all customers payment terms based on the oldest invoice.  So far I have the following code:

```
UPDATE [CUSTOMERS - Main]
SET    Payterms = 0
FROM   (SELECT Max(INVOICES.InvoiceDate) AS LastInvoice,
               Datediff(day, Max(INVOICES.InvoiceDate), Getdate()) AS age,
               INVOICES.CompanyName,
               [CUSTOMERS - Main].PayTerms,
               [CUSTOMERS - Main].CreditLimit,
               [CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyRegNo
        FROM   INVOICES
               INNER JOIN [CUSTOMERS - Main]
                       ON INVOICES.CompanyName = [CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyName
        GROUP  BY INVOICES.CompanyName,[CUSTOMERS - Main].PayTerms,[CUSTOMERS - Main].CreditLimit,[CUSTOMERS - Main].CompanyRegNo
        HAVING (Datediff(day, Max(INVOICES.InvoiceDate), Getdate()) > 365)
               AND ([CUSTOMERS - Main].PayTerms > 0
                     OR [CUSTOMERS - Main].CreditLimit > 0))
```

But it's not working.  How do I update a query that has an aggregate function?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? How is anything in the aggregate subquery correlated to the target table? (I only see `[COMPANY - Main]` mentioned once.) Who names your tables, and can I thwack their wrists with a ruler? Also `MAX(INVOICES.InvoiceDate)` will get the newest invoice, not the oldest.

Comment: That was a typo, corrected.  It should be [CUSTOMERS - Main].  Table naming is a legacy left over from inherited code.  MAX(INVOICES.InvoiceDate) will return the last time the customer used our services.  Any customers older than 365 days should have their payterms set to 0.  That's why MAX is used.  Not working means I get the aggregate function not supported without HAVING clause error.

Comment: So to simplify what you're after, are you just trying to set `payterms = 0` for any customer that doesn't have an invoice in the last 365 days?

Comment: Yes Aaron, that's it.  Have I gone down a complicated route?!!!  #tired!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a much tidier approach, though I may be off by a day from your actual intention, e.g. today is December 10, do you want to exclude customers with any invoice newer than December 10 of last year, or December 11? This excludes customers with an invoice newer than December 10.

```
DECLARE @cutoff DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE());

UPDATE c SET Payterms = 0
  FROM dbo.[CUSTOMERS - Main] AS c
  WHERE (c.PayTerms > 0 OR c.CreditLimit > 0)
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.INVOICES AS i
      WHERE i.CompanyName = c.CompanyName
      AND InvoiceDate >= @cutoff
  );
```

Comment: Awesome!  Works a charm.  Time for bed as I am clearly bushed!

Comment: +1 Way to get to the underlying problem - I was about to blindly write a CTE along the lines of OP's original approach without thinking about it. Congrats on 100k rep!